# kubernetes: specifying maxUnavailable in both Deployment and PDB

Tags: kubernetes

Assuming I have a `Deployment` with a specific value set to the `.spec.strategy.rollingUpdate.maxUnavailable` field.

Then I deploy a `PodDisruptionBudget` attached to the deployment above, setting its `spec.maxUnavailable` field to a value different to the above.

Which one will prevail?

Comment: the later one will.

Comment: @ShudiptaSharma actually PDBs would be irrelevant in this case, see my answer below. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69541729/poddisruptionbudget-has-no-effect-when-deleting-a-pod.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By interpreting the documentation, it seems that it depends on the event.

For a rolling update, the Deployment's `maxUnavailable` will be in effect, even if the PodDisruptionBudget specifies a smaller value.

But for an eviction, the PodDisruptionBudget's `maxUnavailable` will prevail, even if the Deployment specifies a smaller value.

---

The documentation does not explicitly compare these two settings, but from the way the documentation is written, it can be deduced that these are separate settings for different events that don't interact with each other.

For example:

- [Updating a Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#updating-a-deployment)
- Output of `kubectl explain deploy.spec.strategy.rollingUpdate.maxUnavailable`
- [Specifying a PodDisruptionBudget](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/configure-pdb/)
- Output of `kubectl explain pdb.spec.maxUnavailable`

Also, this is more in the spirit of how Kubernetes works. The Deployment Controller is not going to read a field of a PodDisruptionBudget, and vice versa.

But to be really sure, you would just need to try it out.

Comment: the event distinction was a good catch; thanks; I accepted you answer but I would really appreciate a link to the docs source, preferably in the answer itself

Answer (score 4):

I believe they updated [the docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/disruptions/#how-disruption-budgets-work) clarifying your doubt:

> Involuntary disruptions cannot be prevented by PDBs; however they do count against the budget.

> Pods which are deleted or unavailable due to a rolling upgrade to an application do count against the disruption budget, but workload resources (such as Deployment and StatefulSet) are not limited by PDBs when doing rolling upgrades. Instead, the handling of failures during application updates is configured in the spec for the specific workload resource

> Caution: Not all voluntary disruptions are constrained by Pod Disruption Budgets. For example, deleting deployments or pods bypasses Pod Disruption Budgets.

Answer (score 1):

The current answers point us in the right direction, but their combination wasn't explicit enough for me. Here's my understanding:

- PDBs only affect the Pod **Eviction API**, which you can't call directly (at least without the use of some plugin like https://github.com/ueokande/kubectl-evict).
- However, other APIs, most prominently `node drain`, do make use of the Eviction API. The latter might be called by some managed procedure, which is the case for Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) version upgrades: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/upgrade-aks-cluster?tabs=azure-cli#upgrade-an-aks-cluster. PDBs will protect you during such procedures.
- Deployment updates use the Pod **DELETE API** directly (and NOT pod eviction), which is why PDBs will NOT apply to deployment updates.

**TLDR** To answer the original question, `.spec.strategy.rollingUpdate.maxUnavailable` will "prevail" in this case  (in the sense that it's the only relevant setting seeing as the Eviction API is not used, and so PDBs are not used).

Related discussion: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/39824