# PodDisruptionBudget has no effect when deleting a pod

Tags: kubernetes

In the documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/disruptions/) it is stated that deleting a pod is a voluntary disruption that `PodDisruptionBudget` should protect against.

I have created a simple test:

```yaml
apiVersion: policy/v1
kind: PodDisruptionBudget
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  minAvailable: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test
  labels:
    app: test
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test
      image: myimage
```

Now if I run `apply` and then `delete pod test`, there is no trouble deleting this pod.

If I now run `cordon node`, then it is stuck as it cannot evict the last pod (which is correct). But the same behavior seems to not be true for deleting the pod.

The same goes if I create a deployment with minimum 2 replicas and just delete both at the same time - they are deleted as well (not one by one).

Do I misunderstand something here?

Comment: As far as I can tell, PDBs don't affect the DELETE API. I couldn't quite find it written explicitly anywhere official, but here's one example: https://www.reddit.com/r/kubernetes/comments/11uq9wj/comment/jcpf62o/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3. Also the existence of this project suggests the same: https://github.com/ueokande/kubectl-evict. And then there's your personal experience above of course...

Comment: You know what, scratch that, it's written directly in the docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/disruptions/#voluntary-and-involuntary-disruptions *Not all voluntary disruptions are constrained by Pod Disruption Budgets. For example, **deleting deployments or pods bypasses Pod Disruption Budgets.***. Those docs are still confusing though, as discussed here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/39824#issuecomment-764458930

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link in your question refer to static pod managed by kubelet, guess you want this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/disruptions/) instead.

`...if I run apply and then delete pod test, there is no trouble deleting this pod`

PDB protect pod managed by one of the controllers: Deployment, ReplicationController, ReplicaSet or StatefulSet.

`...if I create a deployment with minimum 2 replicas and just delete both at the same time - they are deleted as well (not one by one)`

PDB does not consider explicitly deleting a deployment a voluntary disruptions. From the K8s documentation:

> Caution: Not all voluntary disruptions are constrained by Pod
> Disruption Budgets. For example, deleting deployments or pods bypasses
> Pod Disruption Budgets.

Hope this help to clear the mist.

Comment: I have referenced wrong url, I have fixed it now. Surprisingly enough the answer was there for me all the time with **Caution** in bold, but I did not somehow notice it :) Thanks for helping me see it

Comment: I do believe though PDB works without controllers: You can also use PDBs with pods which are not controlled by one of the above controllers, or arbitrary groups of pods, but there are some restrictions, described in Arbitrary Controllers and Selectors. (from [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/configure-pdb/))

Comment: Do you by the way know any other way to prevent "delete pod" from running the same way drain will be by the PDB/ other resource?

Comment: Not quite understand your question, do you have an example scenario?

Comment: I pretty much want the same behavior for delete as there is for drain with PDB: that delete will block until there is a new pod, or if I run a delete by label of multiple pods, then it will respect PDB. I have not found that there is anything like that in k8s and it's probably not that important anyway.

Comment: *"PDB protect pod managed by one of the controllers"* - this is false (at least today), the docs clearly state: `You can also use PDBs with pods which are not controlled by one of the above controllers, or arbitrary groups of pods` (albeit with some rather obvious restrictions: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/configure-pdb/#arbitrary-controllers-and-selectors)